# Convert TimeStamp from to yyyy-mm-dd HH in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

Having a Pandas DataFrame with a column of TimeStamp  yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS timezone (e.g. 2020-06-01 04:26:00-05:00), how to extract new column with only yyyy-mm-dd HH

```
Tried:
df.index = df.Time.to_period(freq='T').index


Result in: yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
df['new_date']=df['your_date_columns'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```